# Views Table - Show Taxonomy Term with Specific Depth

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, theming

I currently have a view that show as table with a list of stores and information about the store (address, phone number, etc.).  Each store is a node that also has a field containing a taxonomy term describing the store.  The taxonomy looks something like this:

Stores

-Convenience

--Chain A

---Midwest

---South

--Chain B

---Midwest

---South

-Grocery

--Chain C

---Midwest

---South

I would like to display the hierarchy in columns in the table.  For example, a store in the South from Chain B should look like this:

**Entity Type        Store Type         Chain        Region      Address                  Phone Number**  

 Stores               Convenience     Chain B    South        123 Example Blvd     (123) 456-7890

Currently, I can't figure out how to get any of the parent taxonomy terms to show, I can only get the term "South" to show.

Using Drupal 7, Views 3.  Any help is appreciated!